# Facebook comments plugin - how to sort comments?

Tags: facebook

I have FB comments plugin here : www.turie.eu and it works, but sorting is little bit odd. How to get that arrow on the top to access sorting options? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've "solved" it:) Sorting option become automatically available when some comments are added. I have about 13 comments and it works!

Answer (score 6):

I have already answered this one at another topic, but i`ll repeat it :)

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="your-website" data-num-posts="5" data-width="638" data-order-by="reverse_time"></div>
```

So anyway the key thing to set is **data-order-by="reverse_time"**.

Comment: Works with the latest version of Facebook Comments Plugin, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Facebook not allowed external sort/order tags or command but im solved easy steps :) `http://connect.facebook.net/sk_SK/all.js` file editing and running on your local server

Steps

1. search/find `colorscheme:this.getAttribute('colorscheme')` in all.js`
2. change this line `order_by:'reverse_time'`
3. save it !

   - If you want other default order just allowed this options `reverse_time`
     `time`
     `social`
   - and dont forget to change facebook js address on your comment page

`<div id="fb-cont"><script src="http://yourwesite.com/all.js"></script>`

Comment: When was the last time you used this option?  I can't seem to get my site to work with this code.

Comment: @Ogun: based on your approach, I digged a bit more on the "all.js" Javascript Facebook's file and discovered that currently the order is set by the "order_by" attribute of the HTML (DIV) placeholder. So you just have to add order_by="reverse_time" to your DIV element declaration. It seems to work.

Comment: Yes, Facebook uptaded all.js and now easy for default sorting :)

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use this direct link

https://www.facebook.com/plugins/comments.php?api_key=APP_ID&channel_url=https%3A%2F%2Fs-static.ak.fbcdn.net%2Fconnect%2Fxd_proxy.php%3Fversion%3D3%23cb%3Df185df11ab685b1%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252F**WWW.YOURSITE.COM**%252Ff846e27164d9b3%26relation%3Dparent.parent%26transport%3Dpostmessage&href=http%3A%2F%2FWWW.YOURSITE.COM%2FSUBDIRECTORY%2F&locale=tr_TR&numposts=25&sdk=joey&width=470&view_as_moderator=1&controller_id=feedback_1qpSRehzyIefEfw0h&owns_pages=1&command=page&limit=50&offset=0&order_by=reverse_time

Pay attention to WWW.YOURSITE.COM and SUBDIRECTORY between &href=.........&

This forum gave me lots of ideas and work arounds so now I got a chance to pay back a little.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The solution of Nemanja works even with fb:comments tag.

Adding **data-order-by="reverse_time"** as an attribute to the comment box tag allows you to sort the comments by reverse time order.